# 'Failed to compile' Error in GitHub Actions CI/CD for React App Build

Tags: reactjs, github-actions

I am trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline for my React app using GitHub Actions. The workflow includes building the app and deploying it to AWS S3 and CloudFront. However, I am encountering the following error during the build step:

```
Run npm run build
  

> tejas_portfolio_website@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

[eslint] 
src/index.js
Syntax error: [BABEL] /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/src/index.js: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object' (0:undefined)
Require stack:
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/create.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/@rollup/plugin-babel/dist/index.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/workbox-build/build/lib/bundle.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js (While processing: "/home/runner/work/www.tejasportofolio.com/www.tejasportofolio.com/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/prod.js")


Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`
```

It appears to be a problem related to Babel and ESLint. Here's my GitHub Actions YAML file:

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy React App to CloudFront

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  fork: []

env:
  ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: true
  BUCKET: www.tejasportofolio.com
  DIST: build
  REGION: ap-south-1
  DIST_ID: OOOOOOOOOOOOO

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Build and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.REGION }}

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          node --version
          npm ci --production

      - name: Build Static Website
        run: npm run build

      - name: Copy files to the production website with the AWS CLI
        run: |
          aws s3 sync --delete ${{ env.DIST }} s3://${{ env.BUCKET }}

      - name: Create CloudFront Invalidation
        run: |
          aws cloudfront create-invalidation \
            --distribution-id ${{ env.DIST_ID }} \
            --paths "/*"
```

I've also ensured that my AWS credentials are correctly configured in GitHub Secrets. The deployment to S3 and CloudFront is supposed to follow this workflow, but it's failing at the build step.

Comment: What happens when you remove `node_modules` locally and run `npm ci --production` and then `npm run build`?

Comment: the error says that "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is missing, Install it and configure it in your babel settings.

Comment: @Konrad I tried with removing 'node_modules' and the project dependencies and then run the 'npm ci --production' it reinstall all the dependencies  that project require the project is working perfect on local host with 'npm start' but again when I do commit something then the workflow showing error again.
More suggestion to try out!

Comment: @clay 
`
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
`
I install the @babel/plugin this is from package.json
any more suggestion

Comment: babel has its own config file  (babel.config.js, .babelrc, etc.) https://babeljs.io/docs/config-files and you must configure the plugin inside that file as in the first answer to this question. I recommend you to  run a docker container on your local machine and try to install and build your project inside de container, avoiding the noise of your personal configuration (global packages, ide files, runtime version...)